# Trouble with member function accepting template function pointer

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a member method on my `array` class for sorting. I typedef'd two function pointers in my class one for a generic sorting method, and the other for the comparator. I'm having trouble navigating through the errors to determine exactly what is wrong with the way I'm calling it. I hope I've provided enough information, but here's what I got.

The error I'm getting:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:222:67: error: no matching function for call to ‘array<int>::sort(<unresolved overloaded function type>, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
 sort(wrap_insertion_sort_recursive<int>, custom_comparator<int>);
                                                                ^
main.cpp:55:6: note: candidate: void array<T>::sort(array<T>::p_sort_func, array<T>::p_comparator_func) [with T = int; array<T>::p_sort_func = void (*)(array<int>&, bool (*)(int, int)); array<T>::p_comparator_func = bool (*)(int, int)]
 void array<T>::sort(array<T>::p_sort_func sort_func,
      ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:55:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘array<int>::p_sort_func {aka void (*)(array<int>&, bool (*)(int, int))}’
```

I'm defining my `typedefs` here:

```
template <typename T>
class array {
 public:
  typedef bool (*p_comparator_func)(T a, T b); 
  typedef void (*p_sort_func)(class array<T> &array, p_comparator_func);
  ...
  void sort(array::p_sort_func sort_func,
      array::p_comparator_func comparator_func);

  ...
}
```

My implementation of sort:

```
template <typename T>
void array<T>::sort(array<T>::p_sort_func sort_func,
                    array<T>::p_comparator_func comparator_func)
{
  if(comparator_func == nullptr) {
    comparator_func = this->default_comparator;
  }

  if(sort_func == nullptr) {
    sort_func = this->default_sort;
  }

  sort_func(*this, comparator_func);
}
```

The sort function I am passing:

```
template <typename T>
void wrap_insertion_sort_recursive(class array<T> &array,
  class array<T>::p_comparator_func comparator)
{
  insertion_sort_recursive(array, array.get_capacity(), comparator);
}
```

My custom comparator:

```
template <typename T>
bool custom_comparator(T a, T b)
{ 
  return a < b;
}
```

And where I'm calling it in main:

```
class array<int> a(5);
a[0] = 8;
a[1] = 6;
a[2] = 7;
a[3] = 1;
a[4] = 3;

std::cout << "attempting sort" << std::endl;
a.sort(wrap_insertion_sort_recursive<int>, custom_comparator<int>);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem specifically was with:

```
template <typename T>
void wrap_insertion_sort_recursive(class array<T> &array,
  class array<T>::p_comparator_func comparator)
{
  insertion_sort_recursive(array, array.get_capacity(), comparator);
}
```

Instead of `class` I should have used `typename` as described in this nice article all about `typename` [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html).

So the fixed version would be:

```
template <typename T>
void wrap_insertion_sort_recursive(class array<T> &array,
  typename array<T>::p_comparator_func comparator)
{
  insertion_sort_recursive(array, array.get_capacity(), comparator);
}
```